# Evaluating $\int \sin2x \sqrt{\sin^2x-\cos^3x} \, dx .$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I need some in evaluating the following integral:
$$\int \sin2x \sqrt{\sin^2x-\cos^3x} \, dx .$$

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I take it you mean $\int \sin 2x \sqrt{(\sin^{2}x-cos^{3}x)}dx$.

Comment: Yes I just edited it.

Comment: The result is, according to Mathematica, both huge and non-elementary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write $\sin 2x$ as $2 \sin x \cos x$, which suggests substituting $u = \sin x$ or $u = \cos x$. Before we do this, we must write the expression in the radical just in terms of $\sin$ or $\cos$: The latter is easier, thanks to the Pythagorean identity, $\sin^2 x = 1 - \cos^2 x$, and the resulting form suggests that we choose the substitution $u = \cos x$.

This reduces the integral to
$$2 \int u \sqrt{1 - u^2 - u^3} du,$$
and using a CAS shows that the antiderivative involves the (nonelementary) elliptic integral functions (and are a serious mess otherwise too).

Comment: and after this substitution I have $\int 2u \sqrt {(1-u^2-u^3)}du$ what is the next step?

Comment: This is a good question ! I am just curious to see how it could be solved. By the way, are you sure of $\cos^3x$ ? With $\cos^2 x$ or $\cos^4 x$, I should be more comfortable.

Comment: Could you approximate this by integrating the Taylor expansion of the sqrt?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: I dont think this hint is helpful. You can't really reduce it any further..still

Comment: I think reducing to this point is about as far as one can go with elementary means.